# Visual Studio 2010 IntelliSense window text input field

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Recently, probably by some accidental key-combination stroke during furious development, my IntelliSense window has a small text input field above which is really annoying, because I can no longer just type and hit Enter to use the autocompletion feature.

How do I get rid of it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key combination you probably pressed was Ctrl + Alt + Space, which toggles the completion methods of intellisense.

Can be switched back to the other completion mode by going to:
 Edit-> Intellisense -> Toggle Completion Mode.

Answer (score 0):

this seems like a bug in VS, please see below

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/587691/vs2010-bug-intellisense-shows-empty-text-field-and-stops-working-correctly

and this bug is closed as "Not Reproducable"...

did you try restarting the VS? propbably, that should fix your problem.

If yes, can you try restarting the machine?